# How to stop a JS function from completing until a callback has executed

Tags: javascript

This is my situation:

I am working within the confines of a webapp that provides a limited API. The app has tabs and provides a 'Tab Close' event that I can listen to in my own JS. The problem is, I need to call an asynchronous function to store some data whenever a user closes a tab, but because the tab (and therefore my JS code) disappears once the event listener completes, my callback function with the result of my actions never runs.

`setTimeout` doesn't work because it's just another callback and it also doesn't stop the listener from completing.

What I would need is something like

```
   var end = false;
   saveStuff(function(result){
       if(result.ok){
           end=true;
       }
   });

   while(!end) {
     //Do nothing until callback has returned
   }
```

But JS doesn't work that way. What is the next best thing I can do to achieve something similar?

Comment: Aside from using promises, are you sure you can't put "what must be done after the callback" at the end of the callback?

Comment: This is not possible. `onbeforeunload` must be a synchronous function, you just cannot do anything asynchronous in there.

Comment: Are the tabs actual browser tabs, or is it some form of emulation showing/hiding divs? Is the "tab close" event an actual event which you can prevent/stop? Maybe you can transfer the work to be done to another tab? Or use a service worker?

Answer (score 1):

You should uses Promises:

```
var end = false;
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    saveStuff(function(result){
        if(result.ok){
            resolve("some value");
        }
    });
});

promise.then(function(value){
// do stuff
});
```

The promise will be pending until you call resolve, it will then be resolved and call the function inside of then. value will be "some value" as you resolved with that string.

More on this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be for this would be using a custom event for that:

```
var event = new Event('myfunctioncompleted');

saveStuff(function(result){
   if(result.ok){
       // Dispatch the event.
       elem.dispatchEvent(event);           
   }
});

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('myfunctioncompleted', function (e) { 
   // do the things after event.
}, false);
```